# Can't see new SSD in Macbook Pro 2015 DiskUtiltiy/Terminal but can in Ubuntu live USB

Tags: disk-utility, ssd

The SSD on my Mac died so I bought a new one and installed it. When booting from internet recovery I can't see the new SSD in disk utility or in terminal (diskutil list).

When I boot into Ubuntu from a USB I do however see the disk. I've tried formatting it but not sure I did it to the correct filesystem. Once I formatted it I could mount it in Ubuntu and it seemed to work fine.

When I went back to OSX Disk Utility I still don't see the drive.

Is there any way I can format it to make it able to install MacOS to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I format my blank SSD from OSX Recovery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225227/why-cant-i-format-my-blank-ssd-from-osx-recovery?rq=1)

Comment: I did see that but unfortunately don't have a spare Mac and won't be able to get one for a while so that's not an option.